# Problem with installing rsyslog(Debian).The repository is not signed

Tags: debian, rsyslog

I want to install rsyslog version 8.39.0 in Debian

```
 uname -a
Linux ads-web 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26)        x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I do everything according to the instructions.

Add to  /etc/apt/sources.list lines

```
deb http://debian.adiscon.com/v8-stable wheezy/
deb-src http://debian.adiscon.com/v8-stable wheezy/
```

Install the PGP key in your apt system

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net AEF0CF8E
```

But when I try to update the repositories, I get the following error

```
 root@web:# apt update

W: GPG error: http://debian.adiscon.com/v8-stable wheezy/ Release: The following signatures were invalid: 1362E120FE08D280780169DC894ECF17AEF0CF8E
E: The repository 'http://debian.adiscon.com/v8-stable wheezy/ Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The repository is not signed, so I cannot install rsyslog.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian Wheezy is EOL(https://www.debian.org/News/2018/20180601)

Update your  `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use archive

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

then use `apt-get update && apt-get install rsyslog` to install rsyslog

Comment: It's okay. It all works. I didn't add subnet to the the conf on the log server, and I thought the version rsyslog didn't work on Debian :). Thanks, all works